# Защита от SQL инъекций в PHP

Tags: php, sql, взлом

Не так давно начал интересоваться защитой сайтов от различных атак. Если с xss и csrf все просто, то с SQL инъекциями не понятно - использовать pdo или mysqli_real_escape_string и как вообще грамотно защитить сайт от SQL инъекций. Вопрос: как грамотно защитить сайт от SQL инъекций?

Comment: @Herrgott, хм, а сайты написанные на других ЯП не взламываемые?

Comment: @visman нет, всё взламываемое. Но для современных языков полно для этого готового функционала без костылей. Например helm.js для nodejs

Comment: @Herrgott, если вы не являетесь экспертом языка, лучше воздержаться от комментариев к вопросам по нему.

Comment: @Herrgott как же тогда живут большие сайты аля пикабу, написанные на пыхе?

Comment: @alexx не знаю как они живут, но судя по "This site can’t be reached" на пикабу, а потом только сайт загружается - живут не очень. Причем эта ошибка регулярнейшим образом появляется, что говорит о криворукости языка. Или у тебя есть сводка попыток взлома этого сайта? Может его просто никто не пытался ломать?

Comment: Ну вк например, он вроде на php написан